# SaveGIF in animation package gives blank image

Tags: r

I have to download some .png files from the internet ranging from January 1990 to December 1999, crop them, then create an animation in the form of a .gif file using the images. When I download the .png files, I name them by month and year so the image for January 1990 is named "tmp011990.png" on my computer, April 1992 is named "tmp041992.png", etc. The code for downloading and cropping the images is working just fine.

```r
library(grid)
library(png)
library(animation)
library(ggplot2)

#example code for a single image using January 1990
#this code plots properly with proper cropping
img = readPNG("tmp011990.png")
g <- rasterGrob(img[100:400,40:320,])
ggplot() + annotation_custom(g)

#code for creating the animated GIF, gives a blank white image
saveGIF({
  for (n in 1990:1999) {
    for (i in 1:12) {
      imagename = sprintf("tmp%02i%d.png",i,n)
      print(imagename)
      img = readPNG(imagename)
      g <- rasterGrob(img[100:400,40:320,])
      ggplot() + annotation_custom(g)
    }
  }
}, interval = 0.1, movie.name="seaice.gif")

#alternate code for creating the GIF, displays only the last frame
saveGIF({
  for (n in 1990:1999) {
    for (i in 1:12) {
      imagename = sprintf("tmp%02i%d.png",i,n)
      print(imagename)
      img = readPNG(imagename)
      g <- grid.raster(img[100:400,40:320,])
      ggplot() + annotation_custom(g)
    }
  }
}, interval = 0.1, movie.name="seaice.gif")
```

The expected result of the saveGIF function is a GIF file that is an animation of all 120 months, going from January 1990 to December 1999. When using rasterGrob in the loop, the output is a blank white image. When using grid.raster within the loop, it seems to display each image on top of the last rather than replacing it, so the output is a GIF that displays the last image only ("tmp121999.png"). Is there something wrong with my loop that is causing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, problem solved. You have to use print(ggplot()) when using the saveGIF function.